# In C++20 What's the most succinct and clear way to compute on adjacent pairs in a range?

Tags: c++, range, c++20

I bumped into a simple problem today and I realized with the modern ranges stuff and maybe other stuff in `<algorithm>` there must be an elegant way to express this in a line or so instead of this mess of six lines, but I don't know it.

**Compute adjacent differences:**

```
    std::vector<int> nums = {3841, 16342, 1941, 31299, 26416, 11243};

    auto it1 = std::begin(nums);
    auto it2 = it1;
    it2++;
    std::vector<int> adjacent_diffs;
    for (; it2 != std::end(nums); it1++, it2++) {
        adjacent_diffs.push_back(*it2 - *it1);
    }
```

This isn't really more succinct or elegant:

```
    auto diffop = [](int a, int b) { return b - a; };
    std::vector<int> adjacent_diffs;
    std::transform(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums) - 1, std::begin(nums) + 1,
         std::back_inserter(adjacent_diffs), diffop);
```

Comment: Inlining the lambda in the second case gets `std::transform(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums) - 1, std::begin(nums) + 1,
         std::back_inserter(adjacent_diffs), [](int a, int b) { return b - a; });` which, while not very pretty, is perfectly succinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting the adjacent differences is the same as zipping a range with its tail, using `-` as the operation:

```
tail: [16342, 1941,  31299, 26416, 11243]
  op:   -      -      -      -       -
nums: [3841,  16342, 1941,  31299, 26416, 11243]
```

Which, in range-v3 terms, would be:

```
auto adjacent_diffs = [](auto&& range){
    return views::zip_with(std::minus{},
        range | views::tail,
        range);
};
```

---

C++20 won't have `zip_with` though (or `tail`, though that's the same as `drop(1)`). What you could do, though, is either using the indices:

```
auto adjacent_diffs = [](auto&& range){
    return views::iota(1u, range.size())
         | views::transform([&](auto i){
               return range[i] - range[i-1];
           });
};
```

Or the iterators:

```
auto adjacent_diffs = [](auto&& range){
    return views::iota(std::next(range.begin()), range.end())
         | views::transform([&](auto it){
               return *it - *std::prev(it);
           });
};
```

Comment: The range-v3 solution is perfect. I would be disinclined to bother with the C++20 versions over the original iterator thing. You just don't get the expressiveness payoff. Are they going to fix the lack of zip in a technical report before 2023?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the One Ranges Proposal doesn't add anything to `<numeric>`, so the most succinct way would still be to use `std::adjacent_difference`.

```cpp
#include <numeric>

std::adjacent_difference(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::back_inserter(adjacent_diffs));
```

**EDIT**: A range version of your initial solution.

```cpp
std::ranges::transform(nums | views::drop(1), nums,
    std::back_inserter(adjacent_nums), std::minus{});
```